# Android App Icon not showing correctly on actionbar of different phones

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Hi i have a problem with my app icon. The icon is displayed correctly on the actionBar of the Emulator but for some reasons it doesn't display normally on my device. Unfortunately I don't have another device models for testing.

Screenshots are attched below

[image: App icon OK(Emulator)]

[image: App icon NOT OK(Device)]

[image: Launcher icon OK(Emulator)]

[image: Launcher icon NOT OK(Device)]

To change the app icon I just changed the drawable on the manifest, is this correct ?

```
<activity
      android:name="--ActivityName--"
      android:icon="@drawable/navbarlogo"/>
```

EDIT:

I tried the app on different android version (Emulator). the result is good but not on the physical phone.

Can it be related to the ROM ? On the phone I have the MIUI ROM.

Comment: Check your phone android version and your emulator android version. if emulator android version is higher then phone android version then create emulator same as phone android version and test it then you able to find the problem.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur change the drawable on the manifest icon is the right way to change the app icon on the action bar ?

Comment: sorry, i do not tell you this solution.

Comment: Make sure you have the same drawable name into your folder drawable-mpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc. See [Using configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support) specially these examples: res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png, res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png, ...

Comment: @Fllo I have the same name on all the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the size of your icon image. It should be small in size.